# Comparing multiple arrays and make a top pair in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to compare multiple arrays and get the top pair.

I have arrays

```
$A = array(1, 3, 4, 5);  
$B = array(1, 4, 3, 7);  
$C = array(2, 3, 6, 5);  
$D = array(1, 2, 6, 7);  
$E = array(2, 3, 4, 5);
.
.  
number of arrays will be N number
```

What i need is to compare the array each other with best algorithm in php.

Comparison ex :

```
$A,$B  $A,$C  $A,$D  $B,$C ..... till Nth pair
```

And I need the answer like this $A,$E is the top pair because $A and $E matches with - (3, 4, 5).

I really hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do matching elements have to be at the same position in both arrays? Is `(1, 2, 3, 8)` a good match with `(0, 1, 2, 3)` or not at all? Are element values always ordered inside the array, like in the example?

Comment: I am quite confused. Do you mean to ask "Find the two arrays with the highest amount of matching elements which share the same key position within their respective array? Not summed, but total count." Also, will the arrays always contain 4 elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function for that, making use of [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

```
function getBestMatch(/* provide arrays */) {
    $bestCount = -1;
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $i => $arg) {
        foreach (array_slice($args, $i+1) as $j => $arg2) {
            $count = count(array_intersect_assoc($arg, $arg2));
            if ($count > $bestCount) {
                $bestCount = $count;
                $result = array($i, $i+1+$j);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is how to call it:

```
$result =  getBestMatch($A, $B, $C, $D, $E);
```

It gives the numbers of the arguments that are the best matching pair (zero-based).

The output of `var_export ($result)` is:

```
array (
  0 => 0,
  1 => 4,
)
```

... which means `$A` and `$E` are the best matching pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double `foreach`, `array_intersect` (or custom function calculateOverlap in your case) and save indexes of maxed overlapped arrays into params and return it at the end of fuction:

```
$A = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
$B = array(1, 4, 3, 7);
$C = array(2, 3, 6, 5);
$D = array(1, 2, 6, 7);
$E = array(2, 3, 4, 5);

$arrays = array($A, $B, $C, $D, $E);

function compareArrays($arrays) {
    $maxOverlap = 0;
    $overlapFirst = 0;
    $overlapSecond = 0;

    foreach ($arrays as $i => $first) {
        foreach ($arrays as $j => $second) {
            if ($i == $j) continue;

            //$overlap = count(array_intersect($first, $second));
            $overlap = calculateOverlap($first, $second);
            if ($overlap > $maxOverlap) {
                $overlapFirst = $i;
                $overlapSecond = $j;
                $maxOverlap = $overlap;
            }
        }
    }
    return [$overlapFirst, $overlapSecond, $maxOverlap];
}

function calculateOverlap($first, $second) {
    $overlap = 0;
    foreach ($first as $i => $item) {
        $overlap += ($item == $second[$i]) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return $overlap;
}
```

Output with intersect will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Output with custom calculateOverlap function will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```